# Let $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$ be functions, Suppose that $g \circ f$ is bijective and $g$ is bijective. Prove $f$ is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My work so far is:

for 1-1:
for all $x,y \in A$, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then
since $g \circ f$ is bijective, $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$.
Since we know $g$ is bijective, then
$f(x)=f(y)$

is there a way I can get this down to $x=y$? I'm not sure I'm doing this the right way but this was all I could think of to at least start the problem. I'm not sure how to start solving onto; should I use substitution from knowing that $g \circ f$ and $g$ are surjective to try to get $f(a)=b$ ?

Comment: Split into an injective and surjective case.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. You haven't used the fact that $g\circ f$ is bijective. You wrote "since," but all you did was apply $g$ to the equation you had. You can finish right away if you do this step correctly.

Answer (score 1):

$$g\circ f\text{ is bijective }\iff f\text{ is injective }\&\text{ g is surjective}\tag 1$$

Since $g\circ f$ is bijective, $(\forall c\in C)(\exists !\space a\in A)$ s. t. $c=g(f(a))$.

Since $g$ is bijective, $(\forall c\in C)(\exists!\space b\in B)$  s. t. $c=g(b)$.

As $c=g(f(a))=g(b)$ and $b$ is unique, then $b=f(a)$.

Look at $(1)$.

Hence the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't notice but you actually proved that $f$ is $injective$. 
if $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ and since $(g\circ f)$ is $bijective$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=y$

Now let  $b \in B$ and let $c=g(b)$. Now since $g \circ f$ is $bijective$ so $\exists$ $k \in A$ such that $(g \circ f)(k)=c$. (Notice that $c \in C$). 
So $g(f(k))=c=g(b)$ and since $g$ is $bijective$ so $f(k)=b$ and hence $f$ is $surjective$.

And we are done!!

Comment: I don't see how the OP **proved** $f$ is injective. $g\circ f$ is injective iff $f$ is injective. And if $g\circ f$ is bijective, that means there is a _unique_ $k$.